# Windows phone 8.1 runtime: how to rotate an image according to device orientation?

Tags: c#, animation, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, winrt-xaml

I must say that I disabled orientation events for my purposes, so I could only use the accelerometer.
I'd like to rotate an image, according to the acceleration vector. Tell me if I should use another sensor.
For example, if the app is in portrait mode the image is normally upright, when the phone is in landscape mode the image should make a rotation of 90°.

Comment: What other sensor would you use? Why not the accelerometer? To keep your question useful and appropriate for Stack Overflow, please be _specific_ about what difficulty you're having rotating the image, and include [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that clearly illustrates the question.

Comment: Why did you disable landscape orientation? It would make it really easy, you would not have to do anything

Comment: @PeterDuniho I know how to rotate but I'm not sure what data I need to understand the position of the phone

Comment: @IgorKulman I know but I really must keep portrait mode, that's why I'm stuck with this.

Comment: @PeterDuniho it's not a code problem but algorithm, how should I use sensors to understand when the phone is in portrait or landscape

Comment: The answer to that broad question can be found in the documentation. For any API, Windows Phone included, accelerometer data is provided relative to the device body. Assuming the device is itself not being accelerated, the accelerometer will indicate a 1G force toward the ground. You can look at the components of that force vector to determine device orientation (i.e. if the XY plan is parallel to the device face, then resolving the X and Y components as an angle tells you which way is the ground relative to the device, which is the same as knowing the orientation of the device).